# 220v equipment in different areas of my home having intermittent issue

Tags: dryer, 240v, washer, microwave-oven

I live in united states.
washer and dryer in laundry room in my home microwave and oven in the kitchen area has been turning off after 8-15 seconds of operation every now and then.
oven displays bad line error and washer show PF error when i have this issue. when i researched it seems both issue is related to outlets not providing 240v

I have another oven in the kitchen (on the other side) which doesn’t seem to have this issue.

none of my breakers are tripped. I have been turning breakers off/on and unplugging the power cord and plug back but it doesn't seem to help.

I was wondering if someone can provide me some guidance on how to identify the root cause of this issue and resolution.

Thanks you very much!!!

Comment: I *suspect* this is actually US or Canada, 120V for most appliances, 240V for oven and dryer. But from a strict reading of the text, it could be Europe or almost any other place with standard 240V power for most appliances. **Are you in 120V/240V land or 240V land?**

Comment: updated my post to clarify that i live in united states. thanks!

Comment: Get out your multimeter. Or buy or borrow one if you don't have one. Check voltage in various 120V ("regular receptacles") and 240V (e.g., clothes dryer) to see what you've got. Report back what kind of numbers you find. That will be a big clue.

Comment: Turn off all your 240V breakers.   Does half your house lose power?